# How to correctly convert from if/else statement to ternary expression?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, ternary

If we don’t have a number in `${desc}`, we log out `extId` and if doesn’t have extId, then it goes with empty string.

I tried to convert this:

```js
if (/^\d+$/.test(desc)) {
  console.log(desc);
}
if (!/^\d+$/.test(desc) && exlId != null) {
  console.log(extId);
} else {
  console.log("");
}
```

to this :

```
/^\d+$/.test(desc)
  ? desc
  : ""
  ? !/^\d+$/.test(desc) && extId != null
  : ""
```

But this didn't work. What I do wrong?

Comment: Ik this is not related, but there's a typo: `if (!/^\d+$/.test(desc) && exlId /*<-- here*/ != null)`.

Comment: > "What I do wrong?" Besides making the epression harder to read? (or is it just an excercise?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your question correctly:

```js
const log =  /^\d+$/.test(desc) ? desc : extId ? extId : "";
// Prints: -------------------------^-------------^-------^
```

or alternatively:

```js
const log =  /^\d+$/.test(desc) && desc || extId && extId || "";
```

PS: fix also your typo: `exlId` !== `extId`

Answer (score 1):

Might be Your syntax is wrong to implement the multiple conditions in the ternary operator

It should be like

**condition1 ? condition2 ? Expression1 : Expression2 : Expression3**

```
 /^\d+$/.test(desc)
            ? !/^\d+$/.test(desc) && extId != null ?
            "" : desc;
```

check out this for more info [https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-multiple-ternary-operators-in-a-single-statement-in-javascript/#:~:text=In%20the%20above%20syntax%2C%20we,then%20the%20output%20is%20Expression1](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-multiple-ternary-operators-in-a-single-statement-in-javascript/#:%7E:text=In%20the%20above%20syntax%2C%20we,then%20the%20output%20is%20Expression1).

Answer (score -1):

Here's your ternary statement:

```
/^\d+$/.test(desc) ? desc : "" ? !/^\d+$/.test(desc) && extId != null : "";
```

The above statement if written in if-else form:

```
if (/^\d+$/.test(desc)) {
    console.log(desc);
}
else if ("") {
    console.log(!/^\d+$/.test(desc) && extId != null);
}
else {
    console.log("");
}
```

You can see the issue here. Now here is the correct ternary statement:

```
/^\d+$/.test(desc) ? desc : extId ? extId : "";
```